# Why is the keyboard shorts like cmd+C and cmd+F are not working on IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 version in macOS Monterey?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea-2018

Keyboard shorts like <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> are not working on IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 version in macOS Monterey. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> are working. Kindly help.

Comment: I have no concrete information, but a 4 year old IDEA version is unlikely to get fixes for a half-year old Mac OS version.

Comment: Are they detected in "Preferences - Keymap - Find Action by shortcut"?